# Would installing an alternate boot loader like rEFInd restore some kind of boot screen after upgrading to a PC video card?

Tags: mac-pro, dual-boot, efi

I have a 2008 MacPro3,1 that I've upgraded to a PC video card. I haven't flashed the GPU's BIOS to give me native boot screens since I haven't been able to find a compatible EFI ROM yet for the R9 270X card. However, I would like to get SOME kind of boot screen since I do use Boot Camp and the recent upgrade to El Capitan has made 'blessing' my boot drive a bit more difficult.

I'm curious if installing rEFInd as a boot manager would work instead? The idea being that I presume I would have an OS selection screen once again since perhaps rEFInd is less picky about the BIOS of the GPU?

I've read some documentation on the UEFI boot process but nothing I've seen so far details why the GPU is so specific.

Comment: As this has gathered tumbleweed so far, I thought I'd mention I've never heard of a way to get around the requirement that the drivers must be fully loaded before you can see the screen. Most people keep their old Mac card in the machine for this eventuality. Alternatively, you need to select your boot partition from the OS before reboot. I've never had a Mac with Refind, so idk how that would complicate the issue. I've never needed it so far. I have my Boot Camp on a different physical drive, which I've actually been able to successfully move between different Mac Pros & it still works.

Comment: @Tetsujin: the problem just gets a touch more complicated with El Capitan (10.11) and later since the 'bless' command requires system integrity protection to be disabled, so no boot screen means either disable SIP or fly blind and hope that you can press the right key combinations to start Windows.